# Slow SSL/TLS Handshake

Tags: ssl

In a Ubuntu/Apache2/PHP/cURL setup I am making a SOAP request to a remote server via https. Turns out the first of these request always takes at least 2 seconds, while the following usually have a roundtrip time of 0.4s. I did some logging and turns out the handshake consumes a lot of time with multiple roundtrips. Is there anything wrong with my setup?
See the following screenshot of a typical handshake.

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

Also, the command

```
openssl s_client -connect cs17-was.my.salesforce.com:443 -state -nbio 2>&1 | grep "^SSL"
```

yields the following result:

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:unknown state
SSL_connect:error in unknown state
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
SSL handshake has read 4332 bytes and written 647 bytes
```

Anybody has an idea of where the problem lies?